# Findbugs Eclipse Plugin error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I have installed FindBugs as an Eclipse plugin. When I try to run the tool on a particular project, the following error is thrown by eclipse -

> An internal error occurred during: "Finding bugs in (project_name)...".
>   Could not initialize class edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorFactoryCollection

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Eclipse version-3.6.2
JDK version-1.6.29

Comment: I would uninstall the findbugs plugin, stop Eclipse, make sure on the file system that everything uninstalled correctly, then restart Eclipse and reinstall the plugin.